# scheme in jedit

Tags: macos, terminal, lisp, scheme, jedit

I have been searching for quite a while for a way to get color codes for the Scheme language in Jedit. Anybody know how I can do that? I also haven't figured out how to compile my Scheme code in terminal (mac), so I'm wondering if you could give me some pointers there as well.

Thanks!

Comment: There are actually 2 questions. So ask them separately. In addition, the second one depends on which compiler you are using.

Comment: Well, I thought since the questions where very related I'd ask them in one go. I was thinking about using terminal as a compiler, I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the scheme mode should be installed for your local jEdit install.  To change your current mode, look in the bottom right of your jEdit window and click on whatever is there ("text" maybe?).  It will bring up a dialog where you can select `scheme` as the edit mode.

[image: jEdit mode selection]

If you look in `~/.jedit/modes/catalog` or the `modes` directory of your jEdit install, you should be able to see which file globs are automatically associated with the scheme language already.  You can then add more globs to match whatever file extension you're using for your scheme source files.